# Commenting On a thread

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do comments work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work)

Sorry for all to ask a dumb question like that but I have been trying to figure out how to comment on a question? I see edit, answer but no comment. Is it something because I am new? I have looked at FAQ didnt see it searched it but no good. Again if i am asking this in a wrong place please forgive me. i can see it on my own question but how can i comment some other users question? or is there a way to contact a user?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation - You need more than 50

Answer (score 0):

You get to comment once you've got the `comment everywhere` privilege. :-)

Check here: https://stackoverflow.com/privileges

You'll need 50 reputation to get it.

Answer (score 0):

Although this question is out of place here.

I will answer it since you are new :)

You can go to https://stackoverflow.com/privileges to check out your provileges

Answer (score 0):

Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation), it is a FAQ about reputation. Then look at [badges](https://stackoverflow.com/badges) and earn "Analytical" ;-)